# Java Regex match and replace

Tags: java, regex, str-replace

I have set of some characters as below :

```
[A-Za-z0-9/-?:().,’+#=! ” %& * <>; {@\r\n]
```

I have to write a program in java to make sure input is not having any character out of this set and if they do, I have to replace them with spaces.

How can I achieve this ? Only Java 6 please.

Comment: Also, when you say "out of this set", do you mean you want to replace characters that are _in_ this set, or that are _not in_ this set?

Answer (score 1):

`String str = str.replaceAll("([^A-Za-z0-9/\\-?:\\(\\)\\.,’\\+#=! \\” %& \\* <>; \\{@\\r\\n])", " ")`

Basically, if you have a set that is not in "abc", you use the caret to negate the group --> `[^abc]`

Here is a great guide to better using regex:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

And if you want to test, here is another great tool:
https://regex101.com/

Comment: `"\s"` is not a valid replacement string. It's a character class; how would Java know what of those chars to replace with?

Comment: This won't work in java. You'll have to escape slashes.

Comment: Why are we encouraging this terrible question with an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following. `[A-Z]` matches anything in the range while `[^A-Z]` matches anything not in the range. This will work in Java.

```
String out = input.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\\/\\-?:().,\'+#=!\"%&*<>;{@\\r\\n]", " ");
```